# How to see errors with sourcemaps for NodeJS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I compile TypeScript modules into one `.js` file. Then, I execute this file and it can show some errors during the run.

Even though I have sourcemaps enabled and see them in the end of the file, the error message shows me the line number in the bundle file, like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at /Users/myuser/app/server.bundle.js:545:41
```

Can I make the output show me the original sourcemapped file?

Comment: could you try using this [node-sourcemap](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support), if not try using [node-debuger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-debug) which i prefer to be easy

Comment: As an alternative suggestion, you could run your code through [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)